# regex loop is slow over large files how can solve this?

Tags: c#, regex

I trying to use a regex command with loop over regex expression but is slow for files greater than 500 kb

please help me

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program                                          
{    
    static void Main()           
    {    
        string Value3 =@"((#40y#.*?xlrz)(.*?)(#41y#[\s\S\r\n]*?)(\2))";
        var match = Regex.Match(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\diego\Desktop\pruebatabladinamica\pruebassregex.txt") , Value3);  
        while (match.Success)
        {
            var match2 = Regex.Match(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\diego\Desktop\pruebatabladinamica\pruebassregex.txt") , Value3);  
            Regex rgx = new Regex(Value3);
            match = match2;
            string strFile3 = rgx.Replace(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\diego\Desktop\pruebatabladinamica\pruebassregex.txt") , "$1$5$3+", 1);        
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\diego\Desktop\pruebatabladinamica\pruebassregex.txt", strFile3);
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\diego\Desktop\pruebatabladinamica\backupregex.txt", string.Concat(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\diego\Desktop\pruebatabladinamica\backupregex.txt") , strFile3.Substring(0, match2.Index +match2.Length)));
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\diego\Desktop\pruebatabladinamica\pruebassregex.txt", strFile3.Substring(match2.Index +match2.Length, strFile3.Length - match2.Index - match2.Length ));

            strFile3 = null;
            int oldCacheSize = Regex.CacheSize;
            Regex.CacheSize= 0;
            GC.Collect();
            Regex.CacheSize =  oldCacheSize; 
        }
    }
}
```

how can solve please help me

i have a loop each replace of this loop regex get a string of 10mb and make one replacement but this process is too slow , exist any method for solve this problem

when the file is small , regex process each replace fast –

hi my command divide the string in two then use the second string and find a word near at the begin of string then use the index and match lenght for divide the new string and repeat the same process in a loop –

the regex command find the string fast with string small 500 kb
but for string large  1mb this turn slow

word1 word2 word3 replace

word1 word2 word3 replace1

word1 word2 word3 replace2

output

word1 word2 word3 replace

word1 word2 word3 replace+replace1

word1 word2 word3 replace+replace1+replace2

002-0759586-1#39y#REPARTO 01#40y#002-075958655xlrz10,4#41y##42y#-10.20

002-0759586-2#39y#REPARTO 01#40y#002-0759586xlrz54#41y#0#42y#

002-0759586-2#39y#REPARTO 01#40y#002-0759586xlrz56#41y#0#42y#

002-0759586-2#39y#REPARTO 01#40y#002-0759586xlrz57#41y#0#42y#

Comment: This isn't super easy to read.  What are you trying to accomplish?  What's the loop doing?  Are you trying to replace every instance of a regex pattern in a file with something else?  if so, one call to replace will replace every occurrence and there is no need to loop.  But I'm not fully understanding, so maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: i have a loop each replace of this loop regex get a string of 10mb and make one replacement but this process is too slow , exist any method for solve this problem

Comment: when the file is small , regex process each replace fast

Comment: It would probably be easier for everyone just to explain what you're trying to do. It seems really strange to use the disk in place of system memory as a place to store your intermediate calculations. I can't be bothered to figure out what your code is trying to do, but if you were to explain, we could (almost 100% certainly) suggest a better way.

Comment: e.g. provide example input and expected output

Comment: Is the problem that 1. you have many large strings in which you need to make one replacement, and so you loop over those many strings one at a time.  Or 2. that you need to make many replacements within a large string?

Comment: hi my command divide the string in two then use the second string and find a word near at the begin of string then use the index and match lenght for divide the new string and repeat the same process in a loop

Comment: @zero625 That doesn't explain ***what*** you are trying to do. It only explains your unique way of solving a problem that you haven't explained. Step back from your own solution and try to explain the actual problem that are you trying to solve.

Comment: im triying to do a pivot table

Comment: the command work but is slow

Comment: is faster for files less than 500kb

Comment: Come on... I'm really trying to understand your problem, but drip-feeding incomplete information and repeating the same facts is of very little help. Show a small example of your input data, and the expected output.

Comment: i put the input and output

Comment: im triying to do a pivot table but is slow for large files

Comment: @zero625 The regex pattern that you are using doesn't correspond to your example. It won't match anything. Is there a reason why you're not providing an example of the real data?

Comment: i put a part of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*An attempt at an answer.*

---

Problem 1.  Regex

Existing:

```
 (                                     # (1 start)
      ( \# 40y \# .*? xlrz )                # (2)
      ( .*? )                               # (3)
      ( \# 41y \# [\s\S\r\n]*? )            # (4)
      ( \2 )                                # (5)
 )                                     # (1 end)
```

What it should be:

```
 (                             # (1 start)
      \# 40y \#
      .*? 
      xlrz 
 )                             # (1 end)
 ( .*? )                       # (2)
 \# 41y \#
 (?s: .*? )
 \1
```

Capture group changes (old -> new):

1 -> 0
2 -> 1
3 -> 2
4 -> N/A
5 -> 1

*Benchmark*

```
Regex1:   ((\#40y\#.*?xlrz)(.*?)(\#41y\#[\s\S\r\n]*?)(\2))
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   1
Elapsed Time:    4.04 s,   4042.77 ms,   4042771 µs


Regex2:   ((\#40y\#.*?xlrz)(.*?)\#41y\#(?s:.*?)\2)
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   1
Elapsed Time:    1.91 s,   1913.65 ms,   1913650 µs
```

The general regex problem:
You are delimiting a string with what is captured in *Group 1*.
The problem is group 1 contains a middle sub-expression `.*?` which is
a hole that *backtracking* drives a truck through.
This probably can't be avoided, but since you are only matching *once* each
time, it might not make a difference.

---

Problem 2. Regex

Never remake a regex within a loop construct. Make it once outside the loop.
If you feel you need to use the same regex twice within the same loop,
red flags should go up as this is never necessary.

If you do however, make two separate regex var's of the same regex.
I.e. `Regex rgx1 = new Regex(Value3);  Regex rgx2 = new Regex(Value3);`
then access the object instance methods (not class methods) for matching.

---

Problem 3. Program flow

You are manipulating a single file, `C:\Users\diego\Desktop\pruebatabladinamica\pruebassregex.txt`

Within a loop, you constantly read it, manipulate it, then write it.
This is problematic at best.
The only reason to ever do this would be to make temporary copies, not what
you're doing with it now.
If you think for some reason you're saving memory resources, you'd be mistaken.
For one, the *stack* is of limited size as compared to the *heap*.

Once you have the *ORIGINAL* file read into a string variable, do *all* the
operations on that string, then as a last step, write it out to the file.

This part of your code is inappropriate, but used as an example:

```
string strFile3 = rgx.Replace(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\diego\Desktop\pruebatabladinamica\pruebassregex.txt") , "$1$5$3+", 1);        
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\diego\Desktop\pruebatabladinamica\pruebassregex.txt", strFile3);
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\diego\Desktop\pruebatabladinamica\backupregex.txt", string.Concat(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\diego\Desktop\pruebatabladinamica\backupregex.txt") , strFile3.Substring(0, match2.Index +match2.Length)));
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\diego\Desktop\pruebatabladinamica\pruebassregex.txt", strFile3.Substring(match2.Index +match2.Length, strFile3.Length - match2.Index - match2.Length ));
```

All can be reduced to the manipulation of `strFile3` without doing the
intense overhead of reading and writing and thrashing the disk.

In actuality, this is what is causing the performance lag you see on a larger
file.

---

End of attempt ..